# Replace by current domain

Tags: jquery, url, href, location-href

I have a link : http://fakedomain.net/path

I want to replace dynamically the link with the **current domain** name like this : http://currentdomain.com/path

```
$('.link a').each(function(){
    this.href = this.href.replace('http://fakedomaine.net/', WHAT_GOES_HERE);
});
```

But I am blocked at this point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
this.href = this.href.replace('http://fakedomaine.net', 
location.protocol+"//"+location.host);
```

Comment: Working perfectly